# How can I construct a JPQL query to select a specific column of a table given the column name?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I am trying to construct a JPQL query to select a specific column of a table given the column name as input.

This is an example of what the equivalent native SQL query might look like:

```sql
SELECT bc_10year FROM dailytreasuryratesdb._entry;
```

I tried using a positional parameter in the query like so:

```java
@Query("SELECT ?1 FROM Entry")
List<Entry> findEntriesByColumn(String col);
```

but this gives me a `ConversionFailedException`. After doing further research, I found that positional parameters should only be used with a `WHERE` clause, what other approaches could I try to this?

Comment: _Why_ do you need to use a String as the query?

Comment: @dan1st I didn't think about the possibility of using a different datatype as the parameter. This is a good point though because the error stack trace states that "cannot convert `java.lang.String` to `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query`" so this could be something to look into.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no safe way to do this and it kind of seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to be honest. _Why_ do you need to pass a `String` and use that for the selection? What is the reason you are attempting to do this? You might be more successful with the Java specification API instead of JPQL though (although I think you don't really need to do what you are attempting to do).

Comment: The reason I am passing a `String` in is so I can query a select column of the table depending on the user input. Of course I could simply create functions to select each column of the table individually, but that may not be the most robust solution considering there are 12 columns in the table. As of what you mentioned about using a simpler Java specification, I do believe that could also be a valid solution as I could much more simply just construct a query string based off of the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL doesn't allow you to specify the columns of the projection with a parameter because SQL prepared statements cannot be used for that. However, there are other options.

#### Just get the whole object

You could just get the whole objects and then change that in your application code:

```java
List<Entry> findAll();
```

and use it like

```java
List<Entry> entries = entryRepository.findAll();
List<String> projected = entries
    .stream()
    .map(Entry::getWhateverYouWantToGet)
    .toList();
```

However, this will make you query data you don't need.

#### Change your application

Do you really need different queries for each attribute? You probably don't need to get all elements of a column at different places for each column. If you need to do that, you might want to change your database structure from

| Id (P) | Your entry 1 | Your entry 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | def |

to

| Id (P) | entry name (P) | entry value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Your entry 1 | abc |
| 1 | Your entry 2 | def |

where `(P)` means primary key/id column.
Then, you could do a query like

```java
@Query("SELECT entryValue FROM Entry WHERE entryName = ?1")
List<String> findEntriesByColumn(String col);
```

#### The Jakarta Criteria API

The Jakarta criteria API gives you more control over your queries and allows you to create queries from Java code. You can use the `EntityManager` directly and create your own query:

```java
CriteriaQuery<String> query = entityManager
    .getCriteriaBuilder()
    .createQuery(String.class);
Root<Entry> root = query.from(Entry.class);
query.select(root.<String>get(YOUR_FIELD_NAME_HERE));
List<String> results = entityManager
    .createQuery(query)
    .getResultList();
```

(see the example in [the Javadoc of `CriteriaQuery#select`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/criteria/criteriaquery#select(javax.persistence.criteria.Selection))).

You should be able to autowire the `EntityManager` and `YOUR_FIELD_NAME_HERE` is the name of the field in your `Entry`/entity class you want to get.